# Connect to a RESTful service which ends all URLs with an "/"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have to connect to a RESTful service that ends every URL with an "/".

The list of products is at

```
http://company.com/api/products/
```

And the product with the ID 1 is at

```
http://company.com/api/products/1/
```

This is my current `app/adapters/products.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://company.com',
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Is there a way to configure it so that it always ends a "/" at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding the `buildURL` method from `DS.RESTAdapter` and appending a slash should do the trick:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function() {
    var url = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    return url + '/';
  }
});
```